# Stop SAS from trying to resolve & reference within a macro string

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm running a process that lists jobs I want to check the modification date on.  I list the jobs in a dataset and then pass these to macro variables with a number.

e.g.

```
Data List_Prep;
 Format Folder
        Code   $100.;
 Folder = 'C:\FilePath\Job ABC'; Code = '01 Job Name.sas'; Output;
 Folder = 'C:\FilePath\Job X&Y'; Code = '01 Another Job.sas'; Output;
Run;
%Macro List_Check();
 Data List;
  Set List_Prep;
  Job + 1;

  Call Symput (Cats("Folder", Job), Strip(Folder));
  Call Symput (Cats("Code",   Job), Strip(Code));

 Run;
 %Put Folder1 = &Folder1;
 %Put Folder2 = &Folder2;
%MEnd;
%List_Check;
```

It prints the %Put statement just fine for foler 1, but folder 2 doesn't work right.

```
Folder1 = C:\FilePath\Job ABC
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference Y not resolved.
Folder2 = C:\FilePath\Job X&Y
```

When I then go in to a loop to check the datasets, again, it work, so looks for Folder1, Code1 etc, but I still get the warnings.

How can I stop these warnings?  I've tried %Str("&") instead, but still get the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent SAS from trying to resolve the ampersand in the value by using the `%superq` function

```
%put Folder2 = %superq(Folder2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%superq()` macro function is a great way to mask macro triggers that are already in a macro variable. You could either remember to quote the values when using them,

```
%put Folder1 = %superq(Folder1) ;
```

or you could adjust your process to quote them right after creating them.

```
data List_Prep;
  length Folder Code $100;
  Folder = 'C:\FilePath\Job ABC'; Code = '01 Job Name.sas'; Output;
  Folder = 'C:\FilePath\Job X&Y'; Code = '01 Another Job.sas'; Output;
run;
data List;
  set List_Prep;
  Job + 1;
  length dummy $200 ;
  call symputx(cats("Folder", Job), Folder);
  dummy = resolve(catx(' ','%let',cats("Folder", Job),'=%superq(',cats("Folder", Job),');'));
  call symputx(cats("Code",   Job), Code);
  dummy = resolve(catx(' ','%let',cats("Code", Job),'=%superq(',cats("Code", Job),');'));
  drop dummy;
run;
```

P.S. Don't use FORMAT to define variables. Use statements like LENGTH or ATTRIB that are designed for defining variables. FORMAT is for attaching formats to variable, not for defining them. The only reason that using FORMAT worked is that it had the side effect of SAS defining the variable's type and length to match the format that you attached to it because it was the first place you referenced the variable in the data step.

Comment: I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with using `format` if you're also intending to attach a format, rather than using both statements simultaneously.  But for the most part one doesn't attach character formats, so your advice is relevant.

Comment: @Tom, neat approach to executing a %LET statement while a DATA step is executing.  It feels like a limitation that CALL SYMPUTX can't do macro quoting on it's own.  Would you think it would be reasonable to recommend adding an argument to CALL SYMPUTX, which allows you to macro quote the value before it is written to the symbol table? So pseudocode like `data _null_; call symputx("macvar",'jack&Jill','NRSTR'); run; %put &macvar;` would not try to resolve &jil ?